# Integral (log and exp)

Tags: integration

> > Question (Someone asked me for help on this integral and I couldn't figure it out myself.)
>
> $$ \int_{-∞}^∞ log(1+ae^{-t^2})dt  $$

Even taking the Taylor series such that $log(1+ae^{-t^2})$ ~ $log(ae^{-t^2})$

Integral of $Log(a)$ + $Log(e^{-t^2})$

Integral of $Log(a)$ + $-t^2$ ...

still doesn't converge at infinity.
Any ideas?

Comment: Your expansion is incorrect. For large $t$ this is approximately $ae^{-t^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|a| \lt 1$ and using the fact that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \, e^{-k t^2} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{k}} $$

we, get, using the Taylor expansion of the log:

$$\sqrt{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-a)^{k+1}}{k^{3/2}} = \sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{Li}_{3/2}(-a)$$

Comment: Hello, @\RonGordon, do you know what to do when $a>>1$?

Comment: Wolfram apparently numerically agrees with the same formula (only there should be another minus sign in the front)